# Method 'NpgsqlCommand.set_ExpectedTypes' not found

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Hi I am getting below error - method not found void Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand set

[Error Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZey3.png)

I am using Entity framework 6 and Npgsql.EntityFramework version 2.2.7.0 and Npgsql 2.2.7.0.This happens when i am trying to create a ADO.NET Data Entity Model and generate code first from database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those versions are extremely old and no longer supported. Try switching to the newer versions.

Comment: @ShayRojansky I have Installed EntityFramework6.Npgsql 3.2.0.. Now the table selection wizard is getting closed automatically

Comment: If you're referring to the Visual Studio extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration), can you that version too, which VS, which versions of Npgsql and EF6 are in your project? It's hard to help otherwise.